# Convert byte [] to ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java

I have a `byte[]` that i obtained using `Object ArrayList<Obj>`

Can anyone tell me how to convert my byte[] to Object ArrayList?

Coveting `ArrayList` like this:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
 
oos.writeObject(mArrayList);//mArrayList is the array to convert
byte[] buff = bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Do you want one Object per byte, as the boxed Byte? It's not clear.

Comment: i am having an ArrayList< Object> for storing purpose coverted to byte[] and i want to retrive ArrayList< Object> back from byte[]

Comment: Well *how* have you converted it to a byte array? We can't tell you how to reverse the process without that information.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Now you've given us the information about how you did the conversion one way... you need:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
try {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<Object> list = (ArrayList<Object>) ois.readObject();
    ...
} finally {
    ois.close();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm going to go with the obvious answer here...

```
for(byte b : bytearray) {
  arraylist.add(new Byte(b));
}
```

Comment: I think he doesn't want to create a List of Byte